# Swift View Stops Updating Data After Certain Amount of Time

Tags: node.js, swift, websocket

I have an iPad that displays a queue of users in real time via NodeJS WebSocket. When I add a user from my web app, it should display; however, after about half an hour later, the iPad does not display the added users.

I know that my WebSocket is still going, and on two different web apps I can see the updated users.

If I close the app and open it again, the newly added users are apparent on the view.
This must mean that my iPad's Swift code needs some refresh or something, right? Is there a reason why it goes cold and unresponsive to the WebSocket?

Any feedback is helpful.

Comment: You should probably ping your socket.

Comment: What is that? Like logging every time there is a request?

Comment: No, client and server ping each other to detect the dead connection and reconnect if needed. It also called Heartbeat.